# Few questions regarding BroadcastReceivers:

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to create an application that will monitor user calls (outgoing/incoming) and sms (incoming).

So I have created 3 Broadcast receivers:

**IncomingCallReceiver**

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

}

**OutgoingCallReceiver**

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
         Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING (outgoing call) with number: " + number);
         Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call number: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**IncomingSmsReceiver**

```
public class IncomingSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try 
    {
        if (bundle != null) 
        {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) 
            {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + senderNum + "; message: " + message);
                Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } 
        // bundle is null
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);
    }
}
}
```

and defined them all im my Manifest file:

```
   <receiver android:name=".IncomingSmsReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This all working great, but now I have some questions and I need some pointers:

**1.** If I define the `BroadcastReceivers` this way in the manifest file, then correct me if I wrong but if my application is closed/killed then I won't keep monitoring those actions, right?

**2.** What leeds me to think that I need to create a `Service` that will run/register those `BroadcastReceivers`, So I created the following `Service`:

**CallAndSMSDetectService**

```
public class CallAndSMSDetectService extends Service {

IncomingCallReceiver incomingCallReceiver;
OutgoingCallReceiver outgoingCallReceiver;
IncomingSmsReceiver incomingSmsReceiver;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    outgoingCallReceiver = new OutgoingCallReceiver();
    incomingCallReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    incomingSmsReceiver = new IncomingSmsReceiver();

    IntentFilter outgoingCallIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    registerReceiver(outgoingCallReceiver, outgoingCallIntentFilter);

    return res;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(outgoingCallReceiver);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // not supporting binding
    return null;
}
}
```

My problem here is that I can't find the appropriate IntentFilters for `SMS_RECEIVED` and for `PHONE_STATE`, So I have no idea how to I register them programaticly as I did with the `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`.

I will be glad if someone could direct me in the right direction about this one? and how it should be done correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: you dont need service to unregister receiver what i think problem can be with permission in manifest file have you added this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: I didn't created the service to unregister the receivers, I have created it so that even if my application is killed by the system (when it's not in foreground) the monitor will continiue. Because as I understand If I register the receivers using the manifest file they will stop receving broadcast as soon as my application is killed.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you are fully right. When your application is started, you need to create service. There is no need to create instances of

IncomingCallReceiver incomingCallReceiver;

OutgoingCallReceiver outgoingCallReceiver;

IncomingSmsReceiver incomingSmsReceiver;

Try set in manifest priority for receivers.

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope I helped you. If you have questions - ask me.

Comment: But if I register my receivers using the Manifest file (as shown in the code snippet you provided) they will stop receiving when my application is killed. So I need to do it using code from the service using the "registerReceiver" method.

Comment: If your service live all time, receivers will receive events, but only if service is not destroyed!

Comment: Yes I understand, and still the service will usualy live longer then my application when it's not in foregrond.

Comment: If service lives(not stooped and killed), that means application lives. Are you sure, that service is not killed by system?

Comment: Isn't there a possibility that my application will go to background be killed by the system but the service will be still kept alive?

Comment: Yes. But service allowes application to receive events for broadcast receivers

Comment: Try to test your programm:

1)Create service from main activity

2)press back button

3)go to running applications and check your application.

If there will not showing service - your mistake, else - my

Comment: I tested it, my problem is that can't manage to register all 3 broadcastReceivers from the service I created.

Comment: You no need to register receivers from service! Broadcast receivers live all time, while application running, even activity has been destroyed

Comment: So basiclly you are saying that even if I register my BroadcastReceiver using the Manifest file it will continue monitoring even if all activities are killed?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Try it. If service is living.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sticky service to keep the broadcast available.
by this you will be sure that your broadcast is always running even you closed or killed your application.

Comment: what the differences between this and creating a standard/simple service?

Comment: this is binded to the activity while binding it to sticky service will keep the broadcast alway alive

Comment: but for that I need to register all three receivers from the service ,right?

Comment: sure you neeed to register it from the service

Comment: If you will finish reading my question you will se that I have a problem doing that:  My problem here is that I can't find the appropriate IntentFilters for SMS_RECEIVED and for PHONE_STATE, So I have no idea how to I register them programaticly as I did with the Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.